# Why the overload resolution doesn't select the more specialised for a defaulted single template parameter

Tags: c++11, templates, sfinae, template-specialization, template-argument-deduction

With 2 template parameters, the second one as defaulted, I get what I expect when the specialisation results in explicitly supplying what was otherwise the default type to the second parameter. In this case the specialisation is well formed and since that's more specialised, it gets chosen.

When I repeat that with just one template argument, also defaulted, the specialisation seems to be still well formed, explicitly supplying the type which is otherwise default in the base template. However in this case it seems that this is ignored and not considered more specialised. The base version is always chosen.

Can someone please explain why this happens ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct F1 { int operator()(); };
struct F2 {};

template<typename T, typename = int> struct A { constexpr static bool function_call_operator{false}; };
template<typename T> struct A<T, decltype(std::declval<T>()())> { constexpr static bool function_call_operator{true}; };

template<typename T = int> struct B { constexpr static bool function_call_operator{false}; };
template<typename T> struct B<decltype(std::declval<T>()())> { constexpr static bool function_call_operator{true}; };

void f0() {}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << A<F1>::function_call_operator << std::endl; // true; OK
    std::cout << A<F2>::function_call_operator << std::endl; // false; OK

    std::cout << B<F1>::function_call_operator << std::endl; // false; why ?
    std::cout << B<F2>::function_call_operator << std::endl; // false; OK
    std::cout << std::noboolalpha;
}
```

[Here's the online](http://cpp.sh/6wy4d) compiled version with C++14 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I repeat that with just one template argument, also defaulted, the specialisation seems to be still well formed, explicitly supplying the type which is otherwise default in the base template. However in this case it seems that this is ignored and not considered more specialised. The base version is always chosen.

Because the specialization, for `B`, is for `int` (in `F1` and `F2` cases)

```
template <typename T>
struct B<decltype(std::declval<T>()())> // decltype(...) is int, in F1 and F2 cases
 { constexpr static bool function_call_operator{true}; };
```

You instantiate `B` with `F1` and `F2`. Both of they are different from `int`.

Only the generic version matched both `B<F1>` and `B<F2>`.

The `B` specialization is never choose because `T` isn't deducible (from `B<int>` you can't deduce `F1` or `F2`).

Comment: Hmm OK. I think I get it now. It probably chooses the specialisation only if it can substitute the given type literally into the appropriate parameter in the specialisation (only 1 parameter here). As you say `F1` or `F2` cannot be substituted for `decltype(std::declval<T>()())`. I misunderstood thinking that it would look up what needs to be deduced (here that is `T`) and substitute the caller given type (`F1/2`) in place of it (`T`) and then see if everything was valid. That's probably not how it happens. Thanks !